# How do i change a combobox arrow color, in windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, combobox, windows-store-apps

I have this combobox in a windows store app project

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ContactoSelect" Width="200" Height="50" Margin="114,10,27,510" SelectedIndex="0" Background="White" SelectionChanged="ContactoSelect_SelectionChanged">
    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
</ComboBox>
```

i would like to change the color of the arrow, that is black by default.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the control from the Design view

Select the option Edit Style>Edit a copy

A style will be created for the control in the xaml inside Page.Resources as ComboBoxStyle1(name varies according to your x:name)

You will find

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DropDownGlyph" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,0,6,4" Text="&#xE011;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Change the Foreground to the desired color you want.
eg: Foreground="Red" or any other resource binding.

You can define the style globally in your App.xaml so that it can be used else where as below

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}"/>
```

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 it is Edit Template instead of Edit Style.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the arrow for all `ComboBox` objects in your project you could add the following line to your App.xaml file and change "#FF000000" to the color you want.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF000000" />
```

You might also be able to do this on a page/control level by specifying it in the resources.

[From ComboBox styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709912.aspx) under Dark theme brushes